# Can't convert pthreads Stackable object to boolean

Tags: php, object, pthreads, boolean

Why can't be a pthreads Stackable object converted to boolean?

Code:

```
<?php
class StackableAr extends Stackable{
    public function run(){}
}

$obj = new StackableAr();

if(!$obj){
    print "not set\n";
}
```

This causes the following error:
`PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class StackableAr could not be converted to boolean`

Comment: It doesn't make sense to cast these objects to anything other than an array really. use isset

Comment: Sure, it doesn't make sense in this example. But if you have `$obj = null;` at the initialization of the variable you can check this without `isset($obj)`. This works only with "normal" objects. Not with pthreads objects.

Comment: And it also works checking `TRUE`. With `if($obj){` it works fine. But why not with `NOT`?